# Redis alternative for C#

Tags: c#, redis

I started my project in the early days using SQL Server (ORM Mapper) then RavenDB and now Redis.

Now I am looking for a way to get a simplified version of Redis using c# .NET 4.0 classes. I like to mimic:

- The storage mechanism (like dump on every x seconds at y key changes)
- Embeddable (this is most important)
- Sets
- Simple full text search (not using Lucene)

The reason is I am now using Redis (via the ServiceStack client) on a (production ready) Virtual Linux server and on Windows for Development and was thinking about a simplified C# alternative. So maybe someone already has done some work on this subject and likes to share it.

Answer (score 2):

RavenDB have a very good .NET support  http://ravendb.net/

.NET Client API -> http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api

Or

http://brightstardb.com/ A embeddable, and scalable NoSQL database for the .NET platform with code-first data model generation.

Comment: Yes I ran my site for about 2 years on RavenDb. I switched to Redis because I like the set based architecture, simple commands and mainly because I switched to ServiceStack based services instead of Web Api and stumbled upon their Redis client. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, honestly, I didn't see a good  replacement for redis yet, thinking in all those good features and data types it have..

Comment: Another reason is I like to strive to 'publish and forget' deployments. Windows Redis does not seem to be production reliable and with my Linux server I always have to figure out the commands needed to keep it running. So I am thinking about some (async) threaded file dumper for storing all kind of Lists, HashSets. I found BinaryRage and although limited this maybe a good starting point.